# How to change the animation type of dismissViewControllerAnimated:completion:

Tags: swift

I cant figure out how to properly use
modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve 
I want to be able to have the CrossDissolve animation when going between my second view controller and the first one. Here is my code...

```
@IBAction func saveButton(sender: AnyObject) {

    //create sound
    var sound = Sound()
    sound.name = self.soundObjectName.text


    //add sound to tableView
    self.previousViewController.sounds.append(sound)


    //dismiss viewController

    self.previousViewController.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve


    self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(false, completion: nil)


}
```

Comment: What is the problem? Are you getting any errors?

Comment: The problem is I cant figure out how to change the transition style of      
        self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)

(completion is only nil temporarily until i sort this error out)

Comment: When using Obj-C defined enums in Swift, you only refer to the last part. In this case CrossDissolve:

    self.previousViewController.modalTransitionStyle = .CrossDissolve. .CrossDisolve here is just short for UIModalTransitionStyle.CrossDisolve, but the first part is inferred because you are assigning it to a property known to be of type UIModalTransitionType

Comment: Thank you for the help, now what is the actual code i need to put in for my instance? because when i just put self.previousViewController.modalTransitionStyle = .CrossDissolve it doesnt change anything

Comment: How are you setting the value of self.previousViewController ?

Comment: Never mind, I just put   modalTransitionStyle = .CrossDissolve    in override func viewDidLoad(){
     super.viewDidLoad
        modalTransitionStyle = .CrossDissolve
}

Thank you for your help, life saver....